# Possible to set HSTS header in config file when using .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, app-config

I read this link [How to Implement HSTS header in ASP.Net Core 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73376095/how-to-implement-hsts-header-in-asp-net-core-6-0) which adds HSTS via the `program.cs` file.

I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu but no indication of adding it via the config file.

Is it possible to set HSTS via the config file (`appSettings.json` or xxxx.json) rather than adding it programmatically?

Comment: Maybe not. If you put some values in `appsettings.json`, in `Program.cs` you still need to read the values and add them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Here an example:

This is the `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "App": {
    "requireSsl": true,
    "https_port": 443,
    "hsts": {
        "preload": true,
        "maxage": 60, // days
        "includesubdomains": true
        "excludedhosts": [ "www.example.com", "example.com" ]
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

And here `Program.cs`:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // ...

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
                if (app.Configuration.GetSection("App:hsts") != null) {
                    builder.Services.AddHsts(opts => {
                        opts.Preload = app.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("App:hsts:preload", false);
                        opts.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(app.Configuration.GetValue<int>("App:hsts:maxage", 30));
                        opts.IncludeSubDomains = app.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("App:hsts:includesubdomains", false);
                        var excludedHosts = app.Configuration.GetSection("App:hsts:excludedhosts")?.Get<List<string>>() ?? new List<string>(0);
                        foreach (var host in excludedHosts.Where(hst => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(hst))) {
                            opts.ExcludedHosts.Add(host);
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (app.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("App:requireSsl", false)) {
                    builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options => {
                        options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
                        options.HttpsPort = app.Configuration.GetValue<int>("App:https_port", 443);
                    });
                }
            }

            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        // ...

        app.Run();
    }
}
```